# OpenNI linking erros, lots of undefined references

Tags: c++, openni

I am driving nuts....
I'm working on a program to read out Joint Coordinates from an Xtion Primesense sensor with OpenNI and NiTE. I got the program splittet in 3 parts. Main, sensorOpenNI.hpp and sensorOpenNI.cpp. Now while linking the parts together I get lots of errors saying there are undefined references to some NiTE functions. I'm working with Kubuntu and g++. The NiTE and OpenNI libs are in a directory called Include...
Here's the error message:

> /tmp/ccrPQHEg.o: In function `openni::VideoFrameRef::release()':
>   sensorOpenNI.cpp:(.text._ZN6openni13VideoFrameRef7releaseEv[openni::VideoFrameRef::release()]+0x18): undefined reference to`oniFrameRelease'
>   /tmp/ccrPQHEg.o: In function `openni::VideoFrameRef::_setFrame(OniFrame*)':
>   sensorOpenNI.cpp:(.text._ZN6openni13VideoFrameRef9_setFrameEP8OniFrame[openni::VideoFrameRef::_setFrame(OniFrame*)]+0x25): undefined reference to`oniFrameAddRef'
>   /tmp/ccrPQHEg.o: In function `nite::UserTrackerFrameRef::release()':
>   sensorOpenNI.cpp:(.text._ZN4nite19UserTrackerFrameRef7releaseEv[nite::UserTrackerFrameRef::release()]+0x24): undefined reference to`niteUserTrackerFrameRelease'
>   /tmp/ccrPQHEg.o: In function `nite::UserTracker::create(openni::Device*)':
>   sensorOpenNI.cpp:(.text._ZN4nite11UserTracker6createEPN6openni6DeviceE[nite::UserTracker::create(openni::Device*)]+0x13): undefined reference to`niteInitializeUserTracker'
>   sensorOpenNI.cpp:(.text._ZN4nite11UserTracker6createEPN6openni6DeviceE[nite::UserTracker::create(openni::Device*)]+0x27): undefined reference to `niteInitializeUserTrackerByDevice'
>   /tmp/ccrPQHEg.o: In function`nite::UserTracker::destroy()':
>   sensorOpenNI.cpp:(.text._ZN4nite11UserTracker7destroyEv[nite::UserTracker::destroy()]+0x1e): undefined reference to `niteShutdownUserTracker'
>   /tmp/ccrPQHEg.o: In function`nite::UserTracker::readFrame(nite::UserTrackerFrameRef*)':
>   sensorOpenNI.cpp:(.text._ZN4nite11UserTracker9readFrameEPNS_19UserTrackerFrameRefE[nite::UserTracker::readFrame(nite::UserTrackerFrameRef*)]+0x1d): undefined reference to `niteReadUserTrackerFrame'
>   /tmp/ccrPQHEg.o: In function`nite::UserTracker::startSkeletonTracking(short)':
>   sensorOpenNI.cpp:(.text._ZN4nite11UserTracker21startSkeletonTrackingEs[nite::UserTracker::startSkeletonTracking(short)]+0x1e): undefined reference to `niteStartSkeletonTracking'
>   /tmp/ccrPQHEg.o: In function`nite::NiTE::initialize()':
>   sensorOpenNI.cpp:(.text._ZN4nite4NiTE10initializeEv[nite::NiTE::initialize()]+0x7): undefined reference to `niteInitialize'
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>   patrick@ubuntu:~/Koerpersteuerung$ g++ -c sensorOpenNI.cpp sensorOpenNI.hpp -I Include/
>   patrick@ubuntu:~/Koerpersteuerung$ g++ mainSensor.cpp sensorOpenNI.o -I Include/
>   sensorOpenNI.o: In function`openni::VideoFrameRef::release()':
>   sensorOpenNI.cpp:(.text._ZN6openni13VideoFrameRef7releaseEv[openni::VideoFrameRef::release()]+0x18): undefined reference to `oniFrameRelease'
>   sensorOpenNI.o: In function`openni::VideoFrameRef::_setFrame(OniFrame*)':
>   sensorOpenNI.cpp:(.text._ZN6openni13VideoFrameRef9_setFrameEP8OniFrame[openni::VideoFrameRef::_setFrame(OniFrame*)]+0x25): undefined reference to `oniFrameAddRef'
>   sensorOpenNI.o: In function`nite::UserTrackerFrameRef::release()':
>   sensorOpenNI.cpp:(.text._ZN4nite19UserTrackerFrameRef7releaseEv[nite::UserTrackerFrameRef::release()]+0x24): undefined reference to `niteUserTrackerFrameRelease'
>   sensorOpenNI.o: In function`nite::UserTracker::create(openni::Device*)':
>   sensorOpenNI.cpp:(.text._ZN4nite11UserTracker6createEPN6openni6DeviceE[nite::UserTracker::create(openni::Device*)]+0x13): undefined reference to `niteInitializeUserTracker'
>   sensorOpenNI.cpp:(.text._ZN4nite11UserTracker6createEPN6openni6DeviceE[nite::UserTracker::create(openni::Device*)]+0x27): undefined reference to`niteInitializeUserTrackerByDevice'
>   sensorOpenNI.o: In function `nite::UserTracker::destroy()':
>   sensorOpenNI.cpp:(.text._ZN4nite11UserTracker7destroyEv[nite::UserTracker::destroy()]+0x1e): undefined reference to`niteShutdownUserTracker'
>   sensorOpenNI.o: In function `nite::UserTracker::readFrame(nite::UserTrackerFrameRef*)':
>   sensorOpenNI.cpp:(.text._ZN4nite11UserTracker9readFrameEPNS_19UserTrackerFrameRefE[nite::UserTracker::readFrame(nite::UserTrackerFrameRef*)]+0x1d): undefined reference to`niteReadUserTrackerFrame'
>   sensorOpenNI.o: In function `nite::UserTracker::startSkeletonTracking(short)':
>   sensorOpenNI.cpp:(.text._ZN4nite11UserTracker21startSkeletonTrackingEs[nite::UserTracker::startSkeletonTracking(short)]+0x1e): undefined reference to`niteStartSkeletonTracking'
>   sensorOpenNI.o: In function `nite::NiTE::initialize()':
>   sensorOpenNI.cpp:(.text._ZN4nite4NiTE10initializeEv[nite::NiTE::initialize()]+0x7): undefined reference to`niteInitialize'
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I'm calling g++ like this:

```
g++ -o test mainSensor.cpp sensorOpenNI.cpp -I Include/
```

Comment: In general the includes and libs should probably live in separate directories (e.g. `/usr/local/include` and `/usr/local/lib`). You're calling g++ and passing `-I` but you're not linking against any library( `-L` flag)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I realized that after looking into the samples and their Makefiles again. Is there any posibility to show all the dependencies?

Comment: not sure, but you can try `g++ -o test mainSensor.cpp sensorOpenNI.cpp \`pkg-config openni --cflags --libs\``

Comment: Thanks, i'll test it this evening, I don't have pkg-config yet

Comment: am not experienced with c++ and I don't use linux, but recently had a chance to briefly use pkg-config with opencv and it works nicely. I'm hoping it works with openni/nite too

Comment: Did you ever get to solve this? I'm experiencing it myself even though I'm linking everything I'm supposed to, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Try copying the libraries libOpenNI2.so and libNiTE2 like that:

```
sudo cp ./OpenNI-Linux-x86-2.2/Redist/libOpenNI2.so /usr/local/lib 
sudo cp ./NiTE-Linux-x86-2.2/Redist/libNiTE2.so /usr/local/lib
```

then do
    sudo ldconfig 
and now compile the program by adding -lOpenNI2 -lNiTE2